# Quick doubt on an application of the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

In Perloff's Microeconomics With Calculus 3rd edition, on page 63, one proceeds to the differentiation of the following equation with respect to $\tau$:
$$D(p(\tau))=S(p(\tau)-\tau)$$
And the result is: $$\frac{\text{d}D}{\text{d}p}\frac{\text{dp}}{\text{d}\tau}=\frac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}p}\frac{\text{d}(p(\tau)-\tau)}{\text{d}\tau}=\frac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}p}(\frac{\text{d}p}{\text{d}\tau}-1)$$
My doubt is: why is the third member of the equation equal to the one in the middle? I really can't see how to go from one to another. Besides, according to the chain rule, shouldn't the derivative of $S(p(\tau)-\tau)$ with respect to $\tau$ be $\frac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}(p(\tau)-\tau)}\frac{\text{d}(p(\tau)-\tau)}{\text{d}\tau}$? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It looks like its simply $$\frac{\mathrm d(p(\tau-\tau))}{\mathrm d\tau}=\frac{\mathrm d(p(\tau)}{\mathrm d\tau}-\frac{\mathrm d(\tau)}{\mathrm d\tau}=\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm d\tau}-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be correct. ..  Apparently  $p= p (\tau )-\tau $, by perhaps slight abuse of notation. ..

For the second equality note that  $\frac {d\tau}{d\tau }=1$ and use linearity of the derivative. ..